# Libgdx Altering the sprite-batch's shader

Tags: shader, sprite, libgdx, spritebatch

I was just wondering if there is any way to alter the sprite-batch's shader and write a custom shader without having to use a new mesh?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a `SpriteBatch` [constructor](http://libgdx.l33tlabs.org/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/SpriteBatch.html) that takes in a `ShaderProgram`. You can also set it using `setShader()`.

Make sure you include the required vertex attributes and uniforms in your shader however (see the [`SpriteBatch` code](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/SpriteBatch.java)), as the `SpriteBatch` will want to set these.